# YII how to call a function?

Tags: yii

I'm in need of knowing how to call a PGSQL db stored procedure REQUIRING PARAMETERS
from a yii controller and passing it the parameters. Could please any one provide
me (maybe also the community) with a short tutorial including code snippets
about how to deal with this situation or direct me to sources where I can get the
information related to this topic from?

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to call the function from another controller?

In standard yii installation all controllers extend the Controller class as a base class. Therefore you can put the function in there and it will be accessible to all controllers.

```
protected/components/Controller.php
```

Or you could attach function by creating a behaviour:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.component#component-behavior